# Still finding a deleted envelope as completed status and not deleted

Tags: docusignapi

We have an envelope that was completed then deleted.  When we use the API to return envelope status this envelope is still showing as completed and not deleted.  Completion was on Day 1 around 7AM ET, deletion occurred later on Day 1 after 12PM ET.  I would expect that at least after the batch morning of Day 2 it would have updated status to Deleted but it is still showing as Completed.  When is a Completed moved to Deleted status?

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete envelopes that are in a *Terminal* state, which is either

`Completed` or `Voided`.

The full list of potential envelope statuses that can be retrieved through the API (which is different than individual recipient statuses!) is this:

`Created`
`Sent`
`Delivered`
`Signed`
`Completed`
`Declined`
`Voided`
`Deleted`
`TimedOut`

With regards to the status table in the API docs you refer to, I think you might be mis-interpreting how the table works.  The example in the text states this:

- A request with a status qualifier (from_to_status) of “Delivered” and a status of “Created,Sent” will always return an empty list because the request essentially translates to: find the envelopes that were Delivered between the begin and end dates that have a current status of Created or Sent, and since an envelope that has been delivered can never have a status of Created or Sent, a zero-size response would be generated.

So when you say that `Deleted` is a possible to status for all other statuses, that's not accurate.

Comment: Then I'm confused as to why in the API documentation for the getting envelope status change does it show deleted as a possible "to" status for every "from" status?  And its even curiouser that when searching help it says it can only be deleted when in a terminal state (completed or voided) versus created as you mentioned.  also the API documentation lists different statuses than you listed `Created` `Sent` `Delivered` `Signed` `Completed` `Declined` `Voided` `Deleted`

Comment: Sorry you're right, you can only delete from terminal states Completed or Voided.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Not sure what it is I'm misinterpreting. If the from_to_status is Completed then it should return envelopes that have a current status of Deleted where the envelopes were Completed during the given time.
In any case, if I delete an envelope in completed status and then pull the envelope by ID shouldn't the status now show deleted instead of completed?